# Node.js redirect doesn't render result

Tags: node.js

Using express.js,

```
app.use('/admin', workingAdminRoute);
app.use('/v1/admin', (req, res) => {
    const targetUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}:${port}/admin`;
    res.redirect(targetUrl);
});
```

when i run

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3123/admin
```

it does display "Hello Admin" as expected.

But when i run

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3123/v1/admin
```

it only says "Found. Redirecting to /admin".

How to display "Hello Admin" as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command line options so that curl will follow redirects.  A redirect is just a response.  To get the content at the redirect URL, the client has to follow the redirect URL and then request the resource from that new URL.

```
curl -X -L GET http://localhost:3123/v1/admin
```

The `-L` option instructs CURL to follow any redirects.